# Showing Modal View - IOS

Tags: ios, view, controller, modal-dialog

I have a fucntion1 which is calling function 2 for getting some values.
Function 2 presents a loginview and it does some query to a service after login is successful.

In function2, I want to wait until the presented view login view is dismissed. 
I don't want to do in the dismissViewController callback of the loginview.

I am trying code like below however it immediately moved forward even after presenting the view controller modally.

Kindly suggest how can i wait for the viewController to be dismissed in the buttonPressed function below.

```
@implementation ViewController

- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender {

    ViewController *controller = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"modelVC"];

    controller.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCurrentContext;

    controller.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;

    controller.delete = self;

    NSLog(@"before presentViewController");

    [self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];

    NSLog(@"after presentViewController");

}
```

-Thanks, Manish.

Answer (score 0):

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
    //Put ur Code,This is implemented first and then dismiss the view controller
}];

[self presentViewController:(UIViewController *) animated:YES completion:^{

}];
```